# Copying JVM from WAS8 to WAS9 will copy all the WebSphere settings

Tags: websphere

We want to copy all the JVMs running on WAS8 environment to New WAS9 environment.
Using this approach, is that all WebSphere settings will also be copied for all JVMs.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to bring your server profiles and settings from the old version to the new version, directly copying the files involved will not work. You'll need to do a version to version migration to the new WAS9 environment. The broadest overview from IBM on the process is an article called [Migration Knowledge Collection](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27048343) which has links to documentation on how to plan the migration and then how to migrate profiles to the new version.

[This article](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_9.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.migration.nd.doc/ae/tmig_admin.html) has links to the step by step instructions on how to migrate your environment over, depending on whether you have standalone application servers, a deployment manager and federated nodes, or other types of profiles. If you need the old servers to keep running, look for the `-clone` option.